# bring a change from gerrit to local workspace without recording commit id and message

Tags: git, gerrit, cherry-pick

I want to bring (like cherrypick) a change but I don't want to record commit message and/or change-id. Is there any way to do so?

My command from a gerrit site for cherrypick the change looks as follows, which I ran in my project repository:

```sh
git fetch ssh://review-androidsite.com:20000/xyz/project refs/changes/17/3442417/2 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Do you want to "merge" the change with your code/branch or just "take a look" at the change in your local repository and throw it away after?

Comment: I wanted to look into it and ultimately merge it into the existing latest commit using "git commit --amend".

Comment: Ok, so the @LeGEC answer is what you want.

Comment: Yes! That helped it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the modifications on your disk, but not committed, use `-n | --no-commit` :

```
git cherry-pick -n FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I was trying to understand from git documentation, but wasn't clear.